# UTL_MAIL.Send inconsistent behavior

Tags: oracle, email

Based on some parameters the PL/SQL code builds a query and executes it, then sends an email based on the results. The email templates (`HTML`) are also stored in a table and before sending an email I update the template with the results then send the email. I use `UTL_MAIL.SEND` to send emails from the backend (**Oracle**).

**Inconsistency issue**: Currently I have two reports, **both use the same query but with different where conditions**, when the email is sent one of them is received correctly, while the other is received as follows:

```
=?WINDOWS-1252?Q?days?=
X-Priority: 3
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------4D8C24=_23F7E4A13B2357B3"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------4D8C24=_23F7E4A13B2357B3
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head></head><body ><form id="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div style='font-family:Arial'><p>This is to inform you that ....etc
```

The Email header is messed up for the second one, I googled and I couldnt find anything about this issue, it is driving me nuts! I even tried copying the email template from the one that works into this one and it still gave me this rubbish.

Any ideas to why this is happening, or why the email is messed up like this?

Comment: Is there a character set issue?  Is your database using ASCII7?

Comment: How can I detect that? Also if this is the case then shouldnt both emails fail?

Comment: What is different about the data that you try to include? Try to hardcode "1234" on both functions to see if the issue goes away (a.k.a both e-mails now work with 1234). Please post the outcome.

Comment: Find your database character set with this: `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`.  Although if there are `NVARCHAR2` columns there may still be UTF data.

Comment: @JonHeller the char-set is `WE8MSWIN1252` - and no we dont use `NVARCHAR2` type anywhere

Comment: @Gui yea I tried removing all the data and just put in some text and it still produced the same messed up output, I know its something somewhere thats causing this but still I couldnt find it

Comment: @Jafar that is odd. There might be something wrong with the second function. I say that because, without data, the contents of the two functions should be the template alone, which would be identical.

Comment: @Gui yea its driving me crazy, I am sure there is a difference but I am not seeing it :'(

Comment: This had been one of the weirdest issues ever! The problem wasnt with the body it was with the subject, if my subject line has more than **40 characters** it fails!!!! and it was working fine before so maybe something changed on the server side, I dont have a clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For future readers**

The problem wasn't with the body it was with the subject, if my subject line has more than 40 characters it fails!! and it was working fine before so maybe something changed on the server side, I dont have a clue!

**In conclusion:** if you encounter such a problem try shortening your subject and body text and see if that would solve your problem, it did for me!